# Properties of Force

Tags: classical-mechanics

Can you change the duration of Force without affecting the quantity of Force? Let's say I need a very little bit of mechanical Force (being used) but I need to use that Force over a long period of time (days, weeks, months,) to turn a generator.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This greatly depends on what force you are talking about and what you want to use to generate this force.

Comment: As long as you provide enough energy then you can provide the force you want for as long as you want.